# Should Brunch.io build tool copy hidden files?

Tags: javascript, build, build-process, brunch

I've started using Brunch:

http://brunch.io

to build my javascript based application.  I'm using Backbone.js which needs a .htaccess file in place in order to handle routing with HTML5 pushState.

My question: is Brunch expected to copy so-called 'hidden' files like .htaccess?  Because no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to copy the .htaccess file as part of the build process.

I have the file in the app/assets/ folder, which as I understood it was supposed to be copied directly over into public/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default brunch won’t copy any files that start with `.` or `#`, so the answer is no, you’ll have to move it there manually.

I’m looking on making this configurable in the next release tho.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly!  I'll keep an eye out for the next release.

Comment: For anyone who finds this - this isn't configurable in Brunch, but a special exemption was implemented ~9 months ago specifically for .htaccess files allowing them to be copied over automatically: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/646